# Intellij key bindings in File Struture window

Tags: intellij-idea, key-bindings

When in the file structure popup window, the default key bindings for moving up/down are <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>. I prefer to use <kbd>⌃P</kbd> and <kbd>⌃N</kbd> for navigation. Is there any way to change the default settings?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think is possible to change this specific setting. What are you aiming for? Maybe we can find a workaround ;)

Comment: @Arnau Thanks for your comment. I'd like to use <kbd>⌃P</kbd> and <kbd>⌃N</kbd> to move up and down in the file structure window the way I do in the editor. It would be nice to make the navigation keys configurable :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is not possible at the moment. You may want to vote for the relevant issues [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108609) and [2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125655).

A workaround (sort of) may be to use the speed search, where you just type a few of the characters of the element you want to navigate to.